# Disallowed characters in WPA/WEP SSID and Password?

Tags: networking, wifi, wpa

I'm writing a [script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406357/weird-issue-passing-variables-from-text-file) that deals with SSIDs and passwords for wifi connections.

I'm keeping SSIDs/Passwords in a textfile and I want to delineate them with something other than a space, since both SSIDs and passwords can contain spaces.

Are there any characters that I can guarantee won't be in an WEP/WPA SSIDs and passwords?

Comment: I'm reading the specification allows for up to 32 8-bit characters of any kind. I guess I will try storing the data as json.

Comment: If the data can contain nulls, then shell builtins [may have problems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/117549); json is probably a better route

Comment: Asked and answered over on [SuperUser.stackexchange.com](https://superuser.com/questions/223513/what-are-the-technical-requirements-for-a-wpa-psk-passphrase)

Comment: Also, not a UNIX & Linux question at all.